# C# - Setting Proxy without read proxy setting from IE

Tags: c#, winforms, networkcredentials

I have a problem when I want to send file to a cloud.
I wanna make the proxy setting is configurable from my application.
I have set this code

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("my proxy address", port);
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "UserDomain");
CommonClass.request.Proxy = proxy; 
  //Where request is 
  //    public static HttpWebRequest request = null;
  //from CommonClass

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)CommonClass.request.GetResponse();
```

I've set those parameter, but when I run my C# program, the setting is still based on Internet Explorer proxy setting.
 Is there any wrong from my code,.?

Comment: Your code is correct. How did you detect that the request was performed using system proxy settings?

Comment: At first i got an error that read the proxy, i used modem for for the internet connection that it sholudn't use proxy, but if I remove the proxy setting, it has no error, and if i use proxy setting and fill any word on proxy address, I got the same error with the word that i fill in the proxy address,.